# Left align multi-row ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a two part legend with different widths:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(qsec = factor(qsec)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, cyl, fill = qsec, linetype = 'short legend')) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = 'top', label.position = 'bottom'),
         linetype = guide_legend(title.position = 'top', 
                                  label.position = 'bottom')) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.box = 'vertical')
```

Is is possible to left-justify the `linetype` legend to match the fill legend?

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the `legend.box.just = "left"` parameter is what you're looking for?

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(qsec = factor(qsec)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, cyl, fill = qsec, linetype = 'short legend')) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = 'top', label.position = 'bottom'),
         linetype = guide_legend(title.position = 'top', 
                                 label.position = 'bottom')) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
        legend.box.just = "left",
        legend.box = "vertical" )
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @Ian Campbell. Have spent quality hours trying to left align multi-row until I found this solution